# How to stack multiple push notifications using GCM Client?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to stack notifications from a news app. Right now I get 3 different icons in the status bar for 3 notifications. I am following this guide from google to implement the GCM Client.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Heres my code:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

....

private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {
    ....
    PendingIntent pIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(context).addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent).getPendingIntent(requestId, flags);

    Notification mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify((int) (new Date().getTime()/1000), mBuilder);
    }
}
```

I have tried playing around with `setGroup` and `NotificationCompat.InboxStyle` but that didn't work either since a new instance of the service seems to be getting created every time I receive a notification.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are you looking for one big notification like in gmail app that show 8+ new mails in one notifications? you should probably see this: http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html

Comment: is this about pushnotification or system tray notification or u trying to combine 'em?

Comment: This is about push notifications. I want one icon in the  system tray to say something like "4 News Stories" and when you expand it it should show 4 different notifications. You're right, something like the inbox or gmail apps.

Comment: Check the big view notification. The link is in the first comment i posted

Comment: You should look at the [**picture**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify), it's exactly what you are describing.